# Suppressing warnings in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio

I am working on a .Net Framework 4.8 solution in Visual Studio 2022.

I have added `IDE1006,IDE0017,IDE0071,IDE0059` to the suppress warnings field on the build tab of projects in a solution I am working on with the configuration drop down set to 'All Configurations'.

The warnings still show.

I have also tried it with semi-colons instead of commas.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance